# Big space between 2 tables when using excel to latex

Tags: excel2latex

Hi I get this big gap between two tables when I upload the code generated by excel2latex as a seperate .tex file using the \include command. if I however just copy the code and run, the space is not there. Please advice.

Comment: Without seeing an example, I don't anyone here is going to be able to guess what your problem is.  Can you upload a minimal-but-compilable example that demonstrates what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\include{fred}` starts a new page before typesetting the file `fred.tex`. Use `\input{fred}` instead.